# Wiring events for reusable d3 time slider

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to convert this [time slider](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ddff7cd0b1220bc68a58#index.html) d3 block to a reusable module. As you can see in jsfiddle, the brush event is not being called. How do I wire up d3 brush event for this module correctly?

Here is what I have so far

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mukhtyar/L01esnjs/)

Code:

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

  //============================================================
  // Public Variables with Default Settings
   //------------------------------------------------------------
  var width = null;
  var height = null;
  var margin = {
   top: 5,
   right: 5,
   bottom: 5,
   left: 5
  }
  var timeScale = d3.time.scale();
  var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %d");
  var startingValue = new Date('2012-03-20');

  //Private variables
  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(timeScale)
    .extent([startingValue, startingValue])
    .on("brush", slider.brushed);

  function slider(selection) {

    selection.each(function(data) {

      console.log(width, height);
      timeScale.range([0, width + margin.left + margin.right]);

      var container = d3.select(this).append('svg')
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


      container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        // put in middle of screen
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
        // inroduce axis
       .call(d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(timeScale)
       .orient("bottom")
       .tickFormat(function(d) {
         return formatDate(d);
       })
       .tickSize(0)
       .tickPadding(12)
       .tickValues([timeScale.domain()[0], timeScale.domain()[1]]))
       .select(".domain")
       .select(function() {
         return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
        })
        .attr("class", "halo");

      var slider = container.append("g")
       .attr("class", "slider")
       .call(brush);

      slider.selectAll(".extent,.resize")
       .remove();

      slider.select(".background")
       .attr("height", height);

      var handle = slider.append("g")
        .attr("class", "handle")

      handle.append("path")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
        .attr("d", "M 0 -20 V 20")

     handle.append('text')
      .text(startingValue)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-18) + " ," + (height / 2 - 25) + ")");

    slider
      .call(brush.event)


    function brushed() {
      var value = brush.extent()[0];

      if (d3.event.sourceEvent) { // not a programmatic event
        value = timeScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        console.log(d3.mouse(this)[0], value);
        brush.extent([value, value]);
      }

      handle.attr("transform", "translate(" + timeScale(value) + ",0)");
      handle.select('text').text(formatDate(value));
  }


});
}


  //============================================================
 // Expose Public Variables
 //------------------------------------------------------------
  slider.margin = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
    margin.top    = typeof _.top    != 'undefined' ? _.top    : margin.top;
    margin.right    = typeof _.right    != 'undefined' ? _.right    : margin.right;
    margin.bottom    = typeof _.bottom    != 'undefined' ? _.bottom    : margin.bottom;
    margin.left   = typeof _.left   != 'undefined' ? _.left   : margin.left;
    return slider;
  };

 slider.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return slider;
 };

 slider.height = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
      height = _;
      return slider;
 };

 slider.startingValue = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return startingValue;
    startingValue =  _;
    return slider;
 };

 slider.formatDate = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return formatDate;
    formatDate = _;
    return slider;
  };

slider.timeScale = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      timeScale
          .domain([new Date('2012-01-02'), new Date('2013-01-01')])
          .clamp(true);
      return timeScale;
    }
    timeScale = _;
    return slider;
  };

  // create slider
  d3.select('#year-slider').call(slider.width(500).height(200));

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the event handler into the scope of the slider instance:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(timeScale)
    .extent([startingValue, startingValue]);

function slider(selection) {

    selection.each(function(data) {

      ...

      slider
        .call(brush.event)

      brush.on("brush", brushed);  //<-- in the scope of the slider instance

      function brushed() {

        var value = brush.extent()[0];

        if (d3.event.sourceEvent) { // not a programmatic event
          value = timeScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
          console.log(d3.mouse(this)[0], value);
          brush.extent([value, value]);
        }

        handle.attr("transform", "translate(" + timeScale(value) + ",0)");
        handle.select('text').text(formatDate(value));
      }

    });
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/L01esnjs/10/).